# (Discord.py) List of members connected to the voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I tried to do this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def move(ctx):
    channel = bot.get_channel(728854327808229406) 

    members = channel.members 

    print(channel)
    print(channel.members) #print info
```

But when I start the program, an empty list comes back, even with me connected.

Thank you!

[image: Terminal picture]

[image: Discord picture]

Answer (score 0):

It's probably happening because you didn't enable **Privileged Gateway intents** and your bot can't get members from the channel. Enable `Server Members Intent` on the [Discord Developer](https://discord.com/developers/applications) site in the **Bot** section.

[image: discord site screenshot]

Then, add this to your code:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

# choose the one you use:
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="your prefix", intents=intents)
bot = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```